# What is the soundproofing performance difference between ultralight 5/8 drywall and regular 5/8 drywall?

Tags: drywall, sound-proofing

Home depot does not have anything but ultralight drywall. I wanted to know what the difference in performance in soundproofing. There is another local supplier who can get the regular drywall.

I am using it to create another wall for soundproofing. I will also probably put 2 sheets with green glue or an alternative in between.

The ultralight will be fine if it performs at or about the same as the regular, but if it does not then I want to make sure to get the regular and NOT the ultralight.

Comment: It's the mass of the gypsum that provides much of its sound-deadening effect, and even then it's not a fantastic soundproofer. I'd definitely seek out conventional drywall.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm adding another wall inside a room which is also going to seal off the window (sound matters more and it will be up for maybe 1 year or 2), and will probably double it up as well with the green glue or alternative, so it will almost certainly have some noticeable benefits in sound reduction from the outside. There are better materials (e.g. owens corning 703 acoustic fiberglass), but for the price, 2x drywall is the best bang for the buck.

Comment: Circular saw? *For drywall?* You cut drywall with a utility knife.

Comment: By the way, "ultralight" really isn't all that lightweight after all. I looked it up and regular drywall weighs 2.2lbs per sqft, and the "ultralight" weights 1.95 lbs per sqft, only an 11% weight decrease. Not a significant difference in this small use case; maybe in industrial applications it matters but for a small project it's just a few pounds difference. The weight is not going to make much of a difference. Also the mass won't be that much less either since the mass itself is also only 11% less.